# how to retrieve data from the database using rich:inplaceselect

Tags: richfaces

i need to display data from a jsp page using rich:inplaceselect,i would like to give a combination of fist name and lastname as values to rich inplaceselect.my question is how selectitems will be defined in the bean?and of what type it would be?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you declare your inplaceSelect the folling way:

```
<rich:inplaceSelect value="#{bean.value}" defaultLabel="click to edit">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
</rich:inplaceSelect>
```

Your values must be of type SelectItems, containg a value and a label.

```
// populate your selectitems where you need them, getting your data from 
// your database or somewhere else
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
items.add(new SelectItem(...));
```

Access your select items collections like this.

```
public List<SelectItem> getSelectItems() {
    return items;
}
```